# does a chrome cookie on chrome browser works on opera browser?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, browser, opera

How can I know if cookies from one browser could be used on another one?
I [only find this](https://www.bing.com/search?q=does+a+chrome+cookie+work+on+opera+browser&qs=n&form=QBRE&msbsrank=7_7__0&sp=-1&pq=does+a+chrome+cookie+work+on+opera+browser&sc=7-42&sk=&cvid=852E75C48B13467984FDB8AF01B47407&ghsh=0&ghacc=0&ghpl=) but it doesn't satisfy me.

Comment: See [this answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/271710/synchronize-cookies-between-browsers/527668#527668)  why you probably can not do that. Cookies are tied to a session. Each session in a browser is unique.

Answer (score 0):

No. Browsers are programs like any other. Chrome and Opera are two different programs and neither has access to data stored by the other.

Allowing one program to access the data of another is a security risk.